# Moving wepart down while scrolling

Tags: 2010, web-part, javascript, css

We have a wepart page with 2 sections. On the left side is a big task list and on the right side is a short list with informations to complete the task. Both lists are list view webparts. 
Is it possible when we scroll down on the page that the wepart on the right side go down too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple thing to do is use CSS on the element. Giving it a position:fixed should do the trick. You don't have to have the web part scroll per se, just the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the page in SharePoint designer and then wrap a new `div` around the webpart you want to auto scroll.

```
<div class="scroll">
    ...webpart zone etc
</div>
```

Then use below JavaScript

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.scroll').css({
        top: scrollPos
    });
}).scroll();
```